# I am looking for a specific control panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am looking for a specific control panel to contain the 3 gridviews that I have. The user should flip through the gridviews (preferably with no postback). The controls of the flipping should be at the top of the panel. What "control panel" can I use to achieve that aim?

Comment: What do you mean with `flip`?

Comment: pass from one view to another. Like multiview control..but  i dont like that control too much... i want the controls to be at the top..as buttons or something,,When pressed transfer you to another gridview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you mean with "flip", you could use an [ASP.NET Ajax TabContainer](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Tabs-Control.ashx) to organize the GridViews in different TabPanels. With ASP.NET-Ajax you could also load the TabPanels/GridViews asynchronously and also only if visible.

Here are some tips.

- [Lazy-Load TabPanels](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html)
- [TabContainer: Tips&Tricks](http://ASP.NET%20AJAX%20TabContainer%20%E2%80%93%20Tips%20and%20Tricks)

Answer (score 0):

Well no postback means client side, and there's no better way to do this than with javascript!

If you would consider using jquery/jquery ui, then the [ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) are probably what you are looking for.

So now you could create a custom control containing all 3 gridviews, and hide/show them using tabs